# How do I have a label that updates a slider value dynamically (automatically)?

Tags: xcode4, slider, label

I have a label and slider in my iOS application and I have run into this problem.

I want to have the label read the value of the slider, and I have done that by using an IBAction with a button so that when ever the button is pressed, the label updates the value of slider. The code is like this:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", slider.value];
```

It works, so now how do I make the label update the value *as* the slider is dragged?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to handle when value changed and add that as target as below:

```
[yourSlideReferenceVariable addTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethodNameGoesHere:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Define your method signature as

```
-(void)yourMethodNameGoesHere:(id)sender{

}
```

If you feel you would be more comfort doing this in Interface Builder, then 'value changed' is the event with which you need to hook up your IBAction method.